# Sql query with multiple clauses

Tags: mysql

I have a search form something like
[image]

My Database table looks like

[image]

If user type compay name and city i can search that using

```
if (!empty($_POST["company"]) && !empty($_POST["city"])) { 
    $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["company"]) ;
     $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["city"]) ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM companies_active_accounts WHERE Company_Name='$company' AND City='$city'");

  }
```

**But I want such a query that first box should contain company but second box can contain city or state. How to write query for that so that it searches for company with city/state.**

Since city/state are same box. I have given the input field name of "city".

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a or condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM companies_active_accounts 
WHERE Company_Name='$company'
 AND ( City='$city' OR State = '$city')
```